# JQuery fade in code has bug cuasing loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Building one of my first JQuery code snippets to hide some images and fade in some text and seems to work great until your mouse around to fast and it seems to repeat.

Just need some fresh eyes as I have working on this for a while and I am new to JQuery so any advice is greatly appreciated..

I have included link to site and the JQuery and CSS related

[Current Site Under Development](http://bgg.azurewebsites.net/)

JQuery for the opacity and fade

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{

    //on hover change opacity of other images
    $("#slider ul li").delegate("img", "mouseover mouseout", function (e)
    {
        $("#slider ul li img").not(this).css("opacity", e.type == 'mouseover' ? 0.3 : 1);
    });

    //Fade in text located in span
    $(".img_left").hover(function ()
    {
        $(".title.one").fadeIn(500).css('display', 'inline-block');
        $(".description.one").fadeIn(700).css('display', 'inline-block');
    }, function ()
    {
        $(".title.one").fadeOut(50).css('display', 'inline-block');
        $(".description.one").fadeOut(50).css('display', 'inline-block');
    });

    $(".img_center").hover(function ()
    {
        $(".title.two").fadeIn(500).css('display', 'inline-block');
        $(".description.two").fadeIn(700).css('display', 'inline-block');
    }, function ()
    {
        $(".title.two").fadeOut(50).css('display', 'inline-block');
        $(".description.two").fadeOut(50).css('display', 'inline-block');

    });
});
```

the CSS related to the JQuery

```
#slider ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#slider ul li {
    text-align: left;
    left: -375px;
    bottom: 25px;
    display: inline;
}

#slider ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}

#slider ul li a:hover
{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}


.title {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    color: #ED8E29;
    display: none;
}

.description {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 12px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    color: #ED8E29;
    display: none;
}            

.title.one {
    top: 150px;
    right: -20px;
}      

.description.one {
top: 200px;
right: 260px;
}

.title.two {
    top: 130px;
    right: -350px;
}

.description.two {
    top: 200px;
    left: 70px;
}
```

Comment: better, give some in fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the async nature of animations.... you can force jQuery to complete the animations by calling .stop() before methods like fadeIn() and fadeOut() like

```
$(".title.one").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500).css('display', 'inline-block');
```